# Convavity of $f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t-t^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I tell where this is concave down?

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t-t^2}$$

I simply took the derivative twice and ended up with:  $$f''(x) = \frac{-1}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$$

Looking at the graph, this is basically always negative, so that doesn't seem right.    ((-1/2 or +1/2 or infinity are the various boundaries in the choices))

Comment: Note that the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$ is $\frac{2x+1}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$

Comment: Chain rule sneaks up when distracted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your very last sentence means...

Note that the integrand is undefined at $x={-1\pm\sqrt{5}\over 2}$. Are you investigating $f$ only between those values or beyond?

If only between those values, then $f''(x)={1+2x\over (1-x-x^2)^2}=0$ when $x=-1/2$. You can check that indeed $f''$ changes sign here, from negative to positive.

Thus, $f$ is concave down for ${-1-\sqrt{5}\over 2}<x<-1/2$ and concave up for $-1/2<x<{-1+\sqrt{5}\over 2}$.

A plot of $f$ confirms this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  My f'' was wrong, as per the comment above.  I have now verified the f''' < 0 from $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2})$